# Caching scheme for two sites that share DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

Let's assume I have two sites around one DB.
The first is based on FatFreeCRM and handles the business logic, let's call it site_1 and the second one is based on RadiantCMS and handles presentation logic. Let's call it site_2
Some of the pages in RadiantCMS use models from FatFreeCRM (mostly to show them, not to modify). And from FatFreeCRM I am able to add/remove/modify some instances of models.

The problem is that I want these pages in RadiantCMS to be cached. But I can't expire cache directly from FatFreeCRM.

What is the best cache strategy for this case?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest creating an API on RadiantCMS that allows you to expire certain cached pages.  For example:

```
site_1.com/api/expire/sldfj2389283kd
```

You could then call this expire action from FatFreeCRM anytime you want to expire a certain key or collection of keys, and perform the actual cache expiration on RadiantCMS.